# Understand data masking in rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

When reading rland document, it is still a bit of difficult for me to understand:
forwarding patterns, name patterns, bridge patterns

For example, it is difficult to judge which of following is correct.

```
vars <- c("cyl", "am")
for (var in vars) print(dplyr::summarise(mtcars, mean = mean(.data[[var]])))
for (var in vars) print(dplyr::summarise(mtcars, mean = mean({{var}})))
for (var in vars) print(dplyr::summarise(mtcars, mean = mean(!!var)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first one runs w/o errors, but the 2nd and 3rd don't, so it seems like the first one is correct, no? Unclear to me why you'd run the loop inside running the same loop, that's why you get 4 summaries for 2 variables.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're looking for, as you don't have a clear question. Here's a nice review of how rlang is used to shift from interactive use to programming in dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Sorry. I correct the code. It is not run loop inside the same loop.

Comment: If I donnot run the code. I cannot know which one runs without errors. I am looking for how to understand data masking. Then I do not run the code, I can know which one is correct.